# ERROR(can't open File to write) occurs while saving text file

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new to Linux platform  .I am saving my text file but that is giving an error that can't open file to write[As shown in image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQZ6X.png)

Comment: Not a *programming*, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow. If you will ask it on other sites, specify which editor you are using, and where (absolute path) you want to store the file.

Comment: ok  thanks @Tsyvarev